# Write formatted and ordered word frequency to txt file with python nltk

Tags: python, for-loop, nltk

I am creating word frequencies of a document (using nltk) andn I want to write it as nicely formatted txt file for later use.

Writing it works as I want it to (i.e. it writes two tab-delim. columns to a text file with rows representing a pair of the token and the frequency:

`key` is a string and `freq_table_raw[key]` is the corresponding frequency as integer.

```
savedir = open('freq_table_python.txt', 'wb')
for key in freq_keys:
  savedir.write('%s\t%d' % (key, freq_table_raw[key]) + '\n')
savedir.close()
```

I have to things I'm struggling with:

(1) I want to store the same table as variable in my script? I tried to create the variable `freq_out = {}` and adjusted the loop:

```
for key, i in freq_keys:
  freq_out[i] = (key, freq_table_raw[key])
  savedir.write('%s\t%d' % (key, freq_table_raw[key]) + '\n')
```

This gives me `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

(2) And this is the reason why I want to do (1): I want to write this *table* in sorted order (highest frequency on top).

How would I do this?

Comment: `.items()`  if you want key and value, pretty sure nltk also has a version of the counter dict that will give you the frequency using .most_common

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using itemgetter() and freq_table_raw.items()

```
from operator import itemgetter

for key, freq in sorted(freq_table_raw.items(), key=itemgetter(1)):
    print key, freq
```